# Formula error in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

i have a strange issue with phpexcel on a pair of formulas and can't figure the source of the problem. (Other simple math formulas work, only this fails).

Since the php report is quite long i'll get straight to the point.

Setting this formula like this

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("D$cuenta_empleados", "=$'asientos_title'.K$cuadro_row" );
```

Throws me this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'INPUT NOMINA Agosto!D8 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occured' in /Users/PolCPP/Documents/Proyectos/Activos/beneficiat/php/inc/PHPExcel/Cell.php:293 Stack trace:
 #0 /Users/PolCPP/Documents/Proyectos/Activos/beneficiat/php/inc/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5/Worksheet.php(455): PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue() 
 #1 /Users/PolCPP/Documents/Proyectos/Activos/beneficiat/php/inc/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php(194): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5_Worksheet->close() 
 #2 /Users/PolCPP/Documents/Proyectos/Activos/beneficiat/php/classes/Everything.class.php(2361): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('../../reports/1...') 
 #3 /Users/PolCPP/Documents/Proyectos/Activos/beneficiat/php/classes/Everything.class.php(3813): Everything->create_act_entry(Array, Array, Array, Array, Array) 
 #4 /Users/PolCPP/Documents/Proyectos/Activos/beneficiat/controllers/common/generar.php(68): Everything->gen_docs(Array, Array, Array) 
 #5 {main} thrown in /Users/PolCPP/Documents/Proyectos/Activos/beneficiat/php/inc/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 293
```

So to debug it i remove the = to avoid it's calculation. I check it on openoffice. And i see

```
'ASIENTOS Agosto'.K4
```

And adding the = in front of it works.

The second formula i have issues it's a condition one (same issue, it can generate it but it works on php)

```
=IF(D22>O22;D22-O22;0)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The developer documentation states that you need to us US/UK separators in formulae.

Quoting:

> 4.6.4.    Write a formula into a cell
>
> Inside the Excel file, formulas are always stored as they would appear in an English version of Microsoft
>   Office Excel, and PHPExcel handles all formulae internally in this
>   format. This means that the following rules hold:
>
> • Decimal separator
>   is '.' (period)
>
> • Function argument separator is ',' (comma)
>
> • Matrix
>   row separator is ';' (semicolon)
>
> • English function names must be used
>
> This is regardless of which language version of Microsoft Office Excel
>   may have been used to create the Excel file.

so

```
=IF(D22>O22,D22-O22,0)
```

rather than

```
=IF(D22>O22;D22-O22;0)
```

The only exception that applies is if you have set locale settings for formulae as described in section 4.6.5 of that document

The separator for a worksheet in a cell reference is the exclamation mark:

```
'ASIENTOS Agosto'!K4
```

not

```
'ASIENTOS Agosto'.K4
```

Comment: Wow, thank you it worked. Yes i know it uses the internal format,  so i was using an english version of openoffice. But even if it translates the functions to the original format i guess it uses my OS locale for the formulae formatting.

Answer (score 13):

Formula pre-calculation
By default, this writer pre-calculates all formulas in the spreadsheet. This can be slow on large
spreadsheets, and maybe even unwanted. You can however disable formula pre-calculation:

`$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_CSV($objPHPExcel);`
**`$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);` isso resolver**
`$objWriter->save("05featuredemo.csv");`

Answer (score 1):

Im using this PHPExcel class for database import purposes and i got the same error.
Some debugging showed, that this content of a table cell caused the error:

```
=- die Beschaffungsplattform für Geschäftskunden
```

I figured out, that the exception is thrown on purpose at:

PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 288   (current PHPExcel Version v1.7.6)

```
throw(new Exception($this->getParent()->getTitle().'!'.$this->getCoordinate().' -> '.$ex->getMessage()));
```

So i just deleted this exception and returning an empty string instead:

```
$result = "";
```

Its a bad Workaround but works like a charme :)